# Create sub ranges of a greater range based on breakpoints

Tags: python, algorithm

Scenario:

A range of zip codes 83000 to 83999

There are some zip codes which require attention and need to be handled separately:

83221, 83222, 83400

I need to go through this range of zip codes and, if a special zip code is encountered, range a range of all the zip codes that were before it.

Stuff to consider:

- A range passed may have no special zip codes
- A range of zip codes may have two or more sequential special zip codes

A smaller scale example:

Range: 1 to 10

Special numbers: 5, 8

End result:

```
Range 1: [1,2,3,4]

Range 2: [5,5]

Range 3: [6,7]

Range 4: [8,8]

Range 5: [9,10]
```

I'm thinking recursion might play a part here.

One area I'm stuck on specifically is after `Range 2` in the above example. Basically, there's no way to know that `Range 3` should stop at 7 without first knowing that 8 is a special number

Comment: Where is the problem?  You already know that `8` is a special number, given in the problem set-up.  This is simple interval logic.  I want to help, but I don't see where you got stuck -- you seem to have the logic well in hand.

Comment: Loops or recursion probably work equally well. I'd choose a loop. When you do your example by hand, write python code that does the same thing in the same way. Then check if all cases are handled.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need recursion here. You just have to build a current list until you find a special number. Then yield the current list and the singleton with the special number. Don't forget to yield the current list at the end if it is not empty.

```
xs = list(range(1, 11))
s = set([5,8])

def gen(xs, s):
    cur = []
    for x in xs:
        if x in s:
            if cur:
                yield cur
            yield [x]
            cur = []
        else:
            cur.append(x)
    if cur:
        yield cur

print (list(gen(xs, s)))
# output: [[1, 2, 3, 4], [5], [6, 7], [8], [9, 10]]
```

You may also use a pair of indices and yield slices.

**EDIT** To group special codes together, you just need a little adaptation of the loop:

```
def func(xs, s):
    cur = []
    for x in xs:
        if x in s: # a special code
            if cur and cur[-1] not in s: # cur is not special
                yield cur # yield it
                cur = [] # and restart
        else: # a non special code
            if cur and cur[-1] in s: # cur is special
                yield cur # yield it
                cur = [] # and restart
        cur.append(x) # always add the current code to cur
    if cur:
        yield cur
```

Comment: Your solution doesn't handle this requirement: "A range of zip codes may have two or more sequential special zip codes". At least if "may" is taken to mean "should, if possible".

Comment: `[[97020, 97021], [97022, 97022], [97023, 97023], [97024, 97025, 97026, 97027, 97028, 97029, 97030], [97031, 97031], [97032, 97032], [97033, 97034, 97035]]`

97022 and 97023 are both special zipcodes, so it looks like it works.. neat

Comment: @ArndtJonasson I'm not sure that grouping special zip codes vwas a requirement. I saw it like a warning: it may happen... But see my edit.